# Graphical issue on contextual windows and menus when running WAMP on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, wamp

Each time I launch WAMP on my Windows 7 (64-bit), I see some graphical bugs in the Windows UI, such as grayed menu on right-click window (anywhere), menus in applications (Notepad++ for example) and so on.

The only way to restore my initial configuration is to stop the server and reboot the PC. It's not a big issue but I can't find out why this issue is still there, even after having reinstalled several times.

My current WAMP conf is:
Apache 2.4.9
PHP 5.5.12
MySQl 5.6.17

Comment: Strange. Is your graphics driver up to date?

Comment: Yep...But maybe later  I'll go to Xamp or EasyPhp for a try..

Comment: Something is wrong with my computer... I 've just installed wamp in another win 7 with quite the same config and it runs perfectly...

Answer (score 0):

This is normally due to the fact that you have an odd windows theme configured.

Try changing your theme to the standard windows theme, if the problem goes away then that is the problem.

Alternatively it is possible to change this WAMPServer config and it might solve the problem even with an odd theme installed.

Make a copy of `\wamp\wampmanager.tpl` as if you mess this file up it can be quite traumatic.

Edit `\wamp\wampmanager.tpl`

Find the parameter `SeparatorsSeparatorStyle=caption` and change it to `SeparatorsSeparatorStyle=shortline` there are 2 of them.

Save the file, Exit Wampserver, and then restart Wampserver. This will cause a rebuild of the `wampmanager.ini` file and hopefully, Bob is your Uncle.